# Generate a list of functions in R

Tags: r, function, evaluation

I would like to generate a list of functions in R.  Basically, I'd like to generate a list of functions of the form `f <- function(x){a*x}` where I specify a vector of `a` values.  Is this possible?

Or is it possible to specify a value of `a` and then have R interpret the function with `a` evaluated already?  To clarify, if I specify `a <- 2`, can I make R think of `f` as `function(x){2*x}` instead of `function(x){a*x}`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes you can do that. Here's an example

```
a<-1:5

fn<-lapply(a, function(i) {
    force(i)
    function(x) {
        x * i
    }
})


fn[[1]](1)
fn[[5]](1)
```

The only "trick" here is the `force()` function. Because R uses lazy evaluation, it doesn't decode the `i` value until you actually need it. If you don't put the `force` in there, when you go to use a function, it will finally resolve `i` and `i` will just be the last value it was in the `lapply` which is `5` in this case.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand what's going on, this creates the function in five different environments and stores the corresponding value of i in each--is that correct?

Comment: @BioBroo Yes. If you just type `fn` you'll see that they all have a different environment ID. And you can extract the values of `i` from them with `get("i", envir=environment(fn[[3]]))` for example

Answer (score 2):

Something like this may also be handy. You can alter the body of a function with `body` and `get`

```
> f <- function(x) a*x
> f
function(x) a*x

> a <- 2
> body(f)[[2]] <- get('a')
> f
function (x)
2 * x

> f(1:5)
# [1]  2  4  6  8 10
```

The body of a function is a list, and it's elements can be accessed just like any other list.

```
> body(f)
2 * x
> as.list(body(f))
# [[1]]
# `*`

# [[2]]
# [1] 2

# [[3]]
# x
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another solution, which I tried but thought had failed.  We can use a closure, which is a function that returns a function.

```
cl <- function(a){
    f <- function(x){a*x}
return(f)
}

cl(1)(1)
cl(5)(1)
```